# Cant add wsp to solution gallery (dont have permission)

Tags: sharepoint-online

My All mighty Tenant admin, Primary Site Admin, Other Site Admin, Only site admin, Site collection admin, you name it admin cannot upload  a wsp to solution gallery at one of my sharepoint site. 
When I try to upload a file I can select my wsp but then I get "You dont have permission to 'this' site"

I can upload this to other sites

In the wsp there is a workflow, exported from SPD

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I cannot upload a WSP either. Nothing Special about the WSP. It came from a SP2013 On-Premise server.

Answer (score 0):

Should not make a difference whether it has SPD workflow or not. The question is can you save a site as a template (assuming non-publishing). If you cannot, then there is a possibility the site collection is corrupted and you would have to raise a support ticket with Microsoft or discard if not too late.

Answer (score 0):

I did the Powershell method and it worked for me...

http://www.evokeit.com/sharepoint-online-deny-permission-when-uploading-custom-masterpage/